# Distored Image Appears During Social Icon on Image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, css, hover

I have successfully applied social icons to my image, so that they appear inline using CSS. My goal is for them to appear once a user hover over the associated image. However, my problem is that when I try to write the CSS fire the `hover`, I get a **distorted version of the icon** appearing on the image, yet the smaller version of the icon **does appear** on hover.  Here's my CSS:

```
#share-icon img:hover
{
   width: 35px;
   padding: 5px;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: 0;
   margin-left: 75px;
   display: inline;
   visibility: visible;
}
```

And here is an example of the code I have applied to the image:

```
<div id="share-icon">
                <!-- Facebook Share -->
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://example.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://www.simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
</div>
```

If I remove the `:hover`, then of course I lose the appear on image hover. Can anyone help me figure out why the distorted icon appears, while the smaller icon does appear on `hover`? I would write an inline for the, but I know you can only use either CSS or JS for this. If anyone can help with a solution, I would appreciate it.

Comment: We have to see what style rules are applied to `#share-icon img` (without the `:hover`) in order to help.

Comment: ...but even without those, my guess is that you have a specific width applied to the non-hover.Then upon hover, you are telling the image to change to a specific width. You probably don't want the width rule in the hover block. Just a guess.

Comment: @JakeParis Only difference in the style rules, is when you take away the `:hover`. Without that, my social icons appear on the image, with proper sizing (tiny sized). Adding the `:hover` is what makes part of it blow up.

Comment: If I remove the `width` altogether, then I get the distorted icon on its own... right in the center of the given image. If I decrease the `width`, say to like `10px`, then the icon reflects the size change, and I have no large distorted icon. However, add back in the `:hover`, and I get the large distorted icon, but the tiny icon does what it should be doing.